# How to create an object inside a GET request in a DRF APIview?

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am writing an API for a game using APIView for the view and I need to create a game round and game session object in the GET request. The goal is that when a user clicks on the game, a game session consisting of a few rounds is created every time. Let's say a game session only consists of one round.

How do I properly create those objects in the get method? Do I assign something to every field? Do I use the save or should I override the create() Method for both?

This what I have so far:

**views.py**

```
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
controller = GameViewController()
        gametype = Gametype.objects.all().filter(name="imageLabeler")
        gametype_serializer = GametypeSerializer(gametype, many=True)

        # while duration is not None:
        random_resource = Resource.objects.all().order_by('?').first()
        resource_serializer = ResourceSerializer(random_resource)

                if request.user is None:
            current_user = '1'
        else:
            current_user = request.user

        current_score = 0

        gamesession = Gamesession.save({
            'id': controller.generate_random_id(Gamesession),
            'user': current_user,
            'gametype': gametype,
            'created': datetime.now(),
        })

        gameround = Gameround.save({
            'id': controller.generate_random_id(Gameround),
            'user': current_user,
            'gamesession': gamesession,
            'created': datetime.now(),
            'score': current_score,
        })

        return Response({'gametype': gametype_serializer.data,
                         'resource': resource_serializer.data
                         })
```

These are my models:
**models.py**

```
class Gamesession(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    gametype = models.ForeignKey(Gametype, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)

    objects = models.Manager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()

        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class Gameround(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    gamesession = models.ForeignKey(Gamesession, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    objects = models.Manager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()

        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am writing an API for a game using APIView for the view and I need to create a game round and game session object in the GET request.

This is *against* the HTTP specifications. A GET request should *not* create, remove or update entities. This is specified under the [*safe methods* section of the HTTP documentation [w3.org]](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1):

> In particular, the convention has been established that the **GET and HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action other than retrieval**. These methods **ought to be considered "safe"**. This allows user agents to represent other methods, such as POST, PUT and DELETE, in a special way, so that the user is made aware of the fact that a possibly unsafe action is being requested.

Methods that are allowed to have side-effects (update entities) are POST, PUT, PATCH, and DELETE.

This thus means that the browser should make POST calls to create a `Gamesession` for example. Therefore the standard `APIView`s defined by the Django REST framework, will never map an `get` method to logic that will create, update or remove items.

Comment: I get that it's against HTTP specifications but I need it to work this way for the game I am creating. I cannot work around it anymore.